# Regex (python): how to match for certain query

Tags: python, regex, match

I have a string list where every line is like this:

> 1.alfa.america.game

i need to query this line with different parameters, and if matches, print it.
with this example, i get all the lines which have "1" and "db", but also get others, i.e.:

> 11.alfa.cad.base

i don't want to get lines with "11" nor "d.b", only the exact match.
this is what i did:

code:

```
    ID = "1"
    task = "db"
    environment = "a-z"
    location = "a-z"
    fullString = "1.alfa.america.game" #this string can change

    q = re.compile(r'(['+ID+'])+.(['+task+'])+.(['+environment+'])+.(['+location+'])+.', flags=re.I | re.X)
m = q.match(fullString)
if m:
    print (fullString)
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use character class `[...]`

Comment: put the `"+"` inside the group `"()"` and escape the `.` like this: `r'(['+ID+']+)\.(['` etc. also remove the last `.` since your data doesn't end with a `.`

Comment: Also, you should read the documentation for regex so you actually know what all the characters mean https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: Also, you can do this without regex `id, task, environment, location = full_string.split(".")`

Comment: @Boris. Thanks for pointing that out. Beginners have a tendency to jump at the shiny jackhammer when they need to cut a piece of paper and the scissors are right there.

Comment: Also, `.` should be `\.`

Answer (score 1):

A few notes about the pattern, some of which are already mentioned in the comment.

With the current variables, the pattern would be

```
([1])+.([db])+.([a-z])+.([a-z])+.
```

- Here, the `.` matches any character instead of a dot only.
- If you don't want to match 11, you should not use a quantifier for either the group or the character class
- Repeating the capture group `()+` would capture the value of the last iteration, you want the group value as a whole so you can repeat the character class instead
- As strings like `1` and `db` are hardcoded, you don't really have to capture them

Taking that into account, you could use 2 capturing groups instead. As you are using [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) you can omit the anchor at the start and assert the end of the string using `\Z`

```
1\.db\.([a-z]+)+\.([a-z]+)\Z
  ^    ^          ^
  Dot  group 1    group 2
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uKf8hB/1)

```
q = re.compile(ID+r'\.'+task+'\.(['+environment+']+)+\.(['+location+']+)\Z', flags=re.I)
```